# How to deal with nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to nest some ng-repeat tags but I dont know how to, this is what I tried but aint working.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="d in (exportData.result.slice(0, exportData.result.length-2))">
 <tr class="parent"></tr>
 <tr ng-repeat="e in (exportData.result.slice(0, exportData.result.length-22))"></tr>
 <tr ng-repeat="f in (exportData.result.slice(0, exportData.result.length-22))"></tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to display three levels of information in a table so I show or hide the rows depending on the user selection, that fucntionality is done but now I dont know how to deal with the nested ng-repeat.

In the example I'm using the same structure just to print data but eventually that is going to change with a different structure.

Some help with this will be great

Comment: check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/u75us/

Comment: I suspect this will cause an infinite digest loop. `(exportData.result.slice(0, exportData.result.length-22))`

Comment: You can have exportData also in nested way something like thi `[{'level':'level1','child':[{'level':'level2'}]}]` so the child array can be used in your inner `ng-repeat`